# how to install composer for stripe payment in php?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php

I want to install composer on mounted folder in localhost /opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject

But I am unable to do it.

Because on my mac terminal cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject  command not working it says

```
-bash: cd: /opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject: No such file or directory
```

While the project exist. Below is the project full path:

```
nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject
```

The project is in the localhost xampp. And I have to mounted and explore whenever I need to open myProject.

I tried many things but terminal always says no such file or directory exits and I am not able to install composer.phar, composer.json in my project.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you tried to install the composer globally ?

Comment: no, I want to install composer.phar, composer.json in my project.

Comment: in anywhere just run those commands:                                                       
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Comment: reference : https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: I have already run it but not got the files inside my project.

Comment: composer.phar, composer.json

Comment: just run composer install (if not work then run composer.phar install)